# c# string into array (using a multidimensional array?) how should I approach?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Newbie still learning, been trying to search and hack code together for hours now, I think there's something fundamental I'm not getting!

Okay so,I have a string (taken from a text file) - "user1,password,1,0;user2,password,0,0;user3,password,0,0;user4,password,0,0"

I want to split the string into a multidimensional array(I think)

```
userAccount[1]= 
    accountDetails[userName]=user1
    accountDetails[password]=password
    accountDetails[adminRights]=1
    accountDetails[loginAttempts]=0
userAccount[2]=
    accountDetails[userName]=user2
...So on and so on
```

I'd like to use an enum for accountDetails for readability aswell but I can get that working after.

What is the best way of creating this multidimensional array from the string?

Lots thanks in advance,
Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others suggested, creating a class for the data would be a better choice than a multidimensional “array”.

The class could look like this:

```
class UserAccount
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool HasAdminRights { get; set; }
    public int LoginAttempts { get; set; }
}
```

And you could then parse the string using [`string.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) first for `;` and then in each part for `,`. Using LINQ it could look like this:

```
string line = …;

var users = (from userString in line.Split(';')
             select userString.Split(',') into parts
             select new UserAccount
             {
                UserName = parts[0],
                Password = parts[1],
                HasAdminRights = int.Parse(parts[2]) != 0,
                LoginAttempts = int.Parse(parts[3])
             }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend making a `UserAccount` class to hold the data, then making a `List<UserAccount>`.

This is far nicer than a multidimensional array of strings, since it's type safe, and lets you put the logic for working with the accounts directly into the class.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a question of object-oriented programming.

When I first started out, I would also abuse `int` and `string` variables. `int` would be the number of times a user logged on. `string` would be the person's username and the person's email and the person's first name and the person's last name.... wait, what if I just create a `class` that represents the general structure of this Person, and call `Person.NumTimesLoggedIn`, `Person.FirstName`, `Person.Username`, `Person.Email`?

Look into structuring your data in an object-oriented way: http://staffweb.londonmet.ac.uk/~chalkp/proj/ootutor/objects.html

Answer (score 0):

This solution depend if the string data you will read have the same separate for all attributes but you know that the number of attributes for each object is n, in your example its 4.

```
string strTextFile = readthe file here;

string[] strArr = strTextFile.Split(new char[] { ',' });  

Account[] UserAccount = new Account[strArr.length / 4];

int index = 0;
for ( int  i = 0, i < strArr.length ; i = i + 4)
{
    userAccount[index]= new Account();

    userAccount[index].userName =strArr[i];
    userAccount[index].password =strArr[i + 1];
    userAccount[index].adminRights =strArr[i + 2];
    userAccount[index].loginAttempts =strArr[i+ 3];

}
```

Comment: Okay so I get this..But what does the 'x' mean in instancing the userAccount? The bit I mean is " = new Account[x];"

Comment: x is the length of the accounts array
int x = srtArr.length / 4;

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: This assumes that you aren't committed to the string you gave as a format. It's more work, but you can do a non-XML serializer too.**

Even better is to not write yet another serializer. A few attributes and some really generic code, and you'll probably never have to write another. Notice that the read and write method here do not care what the types are, you can use these for any class.

Further information can be found in MSDN for the [XmlElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx), [XmlType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.aspx), and [Serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.SerializableAttribute.aspx)

Your class:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlType()]
public class UserAccount
{
    [XmlElement()]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement()]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [XmlElement()]
    public bool HasAdminRights { get; set; }
    [XmlElement()]
    public int LoginAttempts { get; set; }
}
```

The write method:

```
public static void Serialize<T>(string path, string filename, T entity)
{
    string fullpath = path + "\\" + filename;
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fullpath))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.Serialize(writer, entity);
    }
}
```

The read method:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string path, string filename)
{
    T result = default(T);

    string fullpath = path + "\\" + filename;
    using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(fullpath))
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        result = (T)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    return result;
}
```

And, an example of using these:

```
void XmlTest(string path, string filename)
{
    List<UserAccount> accounts = new List<UserAccount>();
    accounts.Add(new UserAccount() { UserName = "Admin", Password = "123", HasAdminRights = true });
    accounts.Add(new UserAccount() { UserName = "Bob", Password = "password", HasAdminRights = false });

    Serialize(path, filename, accounts);
    List<UserAccount> accountsRead = Deserialize<List<UserAccount>>(path, filename);
}
```